# CKEditor loaded event

Tags: ckeditor, webpack

I'm trying to load CKEditor on demand with webpack. I've tried to build it into the entry chunk and it worked perfectly. And then I got a half-loaded one when I was trying to split it into another chunk.

my code (in coffeescript):

```
  componentDidMount: ->
    require.ensure ["../asset/js/ckeditor.js"], (require) =>    
      CKEditor = require "exports?CKEDITOR!../asset/js/ckeditor.js"
      console.log CKEditor
      editor = ReactDOM.findDOMNode @refs.Editor
      @ckeditor = CKEditor.replace editor
      @ckeditor.setData @props.ele.html()
```

and the CKEditor I got (printed by the console.log line)

```
Object {timestamp: "", version: "%VERSION%", revision: "%REV%", rnd: 352, _: Object…}
    _: Object
    _autoLoad: "ckeditor"
    basePath: "http://192.168.245.128:3000/ckeditor/"
    domReady: (b)
    getUrl: (a)
    revision: "%REV%"
    rnd: 352
    skinName: "moono"
    status: "unloaded"
    timestamp: ""
    version: "%VERSION%"
    __proto__: Object
```

And of course, I also got an exception `Uncaught TypeError: CKEditor.replace is not a function`

I've googled for a while and `CKEditor.on "loaded"` was the only thing I found but apparently it's not going to work as `on` is also undefined.